# Catching RuntimeBinderException in foreach dynamic calls

Tags: c#, dynamic, exception

I've got some code reading some JSON into a dynamic object like so:

```
dynamic listOfThings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(listOfThingsJson);
```

and I'm iterating over them like so:

```
foreach(dynamic thing in listOfThings) {
    string propertyOne = thing.PropertyOne;
    string propertyTwo = thing.PropertyTwo;
    doWork(propertyOne, propertyTwo);
}
```

How can I: catch if I encounter a RuntimeBinderException either in the foreach statement itself or either of the property access statements, but simply ignore execution for that one iteration and continue looping?

Something like:

```
foreach(dynamic thing in listOfThings) { \\if a RuntimeBinderException is thrown on this line
    string propertyOne = thing.PropertyOne \\or on this line
    string propertyTwo = thing.PropertyTwo \\or on this line, catch the exception
    doWork(propertyOne, propertyTwo)      \\and move to the next iteration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why can't you use a `try .. catch` block like

```
foreach(dynamic thing in listOfThings) {
try {
    string propertyOne = thing.PropertyOne;
    string propertyTwo = thing.PropertyTwo;
    doWork(propertyOne, propertyTwo);
}
catch(RuntimeBinderException ex)
{
  //log the exception
  continue;
}
}
```

Comment: does this actually catch if (dynamic thing in listOfThings) throws? is it even possible for that line to throw a RuntimeBinderException?

Comment: @FreddyL.if at all that exception thrown then it would be from the property accessor